# BackgroundWorker is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently

Tags: vb.net

I have a background worker to run a loop that queries the database until a value is returned. It needs to launch on load and on refresh. The on load seems to run fine, but when I call it again it fails "BackgroundWorker is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently"

I added the backgroundworker to my form, added the work it needs to do to the doWork event.

```
   Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgwProcessResource.DoWork
        Logic.SetConnection(connectionString)
        materialConfirmed = False
        Dim sqlManager As New BOMIDatabaseManager(connectionString)
        Dim currentInstance As New ResourceInstance(resource, instance)
        Dim results As New Hashtable
        status = Logic.ProcessResource(currentInstance)
        While status.woID.Count <= 0
            status = Logic.ProcessResource(currentInstance)
        End While
        currentWO = status.woID(0)
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bgwProcessResource.RunWorkerCompleted
        WaitingForm.Close()
        'Me.Enabled = False
        currentWO = status.woID(0)
        controller.SelectWorkOrder(status.woID(0), "20")
    End Sub
```

For it to refresh it would have to have already completed so I'm not sure why it's saying it's busy.

Comment: Post the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Use new background worker for every new task. Sounds as you trying to reuse same background worker

Comment: Correct, I created one using the toolbar item.

Comment: There we go. Write code - don't re-use. This will guarantee that you're using different object for each background work. `bgWorker = New BackgroundWorker()`

Comment: each time I do that to I need to declare its handlers after?

Comment: Yes. you need to add handlers, not declare. Declare will be if you assign anonymous handlers via delegates.

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse the worker by supporting cancel. Set the **WorkerSupportsCancellation** property to **True** either in the designer or through code.

```
BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
```

In your refresh button, check to see if the worker is currently busy, if it is, cancel the task.

```
If (BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy) Then
    BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()

    ' Spin up another thread to wait 2 seconds and allow the
    ' background worker to stop so that you can start it.
    ' If you don't want to do this, do something else to allow time to pass
    Dim myTask As New Task(Sub()
                                Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
                            End Sub)

    myTask.ContinueWith((Sub() BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()))

    myTask.Start()

Else

    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

End If
```

This means that your code from above needs to look for cancel and handle stopping the work

```
While status.woID.Count <= 0
    If (BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending) Then
        Exit While
    End If

    status = Logic.ProcessResource(currentInstance)
End While
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    If (BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy) Then
    Else
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    End If
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain why you think this will solve the problem, as well as a citation to relevant documentation or an example. For instance, it seems to be under question whether a BackgroundWorker can be reused; an example showing reuse would be helpful.

Comment: Somebody incorrectly flagged your answer as low-quality. You should add some accompanying text to explain how your answer works to prevent further flagging and/or downvotes. A code-only answer [is not low-quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358757/1364007). Does it attempt to answer the question? If not, flag as 'not an answer' or recommend deletion (if in the review queue). b) Is it technically incorrect? Downvote or comment. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18825118).

Comment: Simply copying a part of [the previous answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/32511418) is plagiarism. If you continue to do so, you will receive a ban.